# Web Assembly Interface types bindings for C++?

Tags: c++, webassembly

It seems like the only way to generate [Interface Types](https://github.com/WebAssembly/interface-types) bindings today is by using [wasm-bindgen](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen) tool, for example:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet(name: &str) {
    // ...
}
```

However, `wasm-bindgen` tool is exclusive to Rust, and I am wondering is it possible to generate similar bindings for C++? So far I haven't found anything in Emscripten or Clang 8+, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: In C/C++ you can use functions directly without needing such decorators using Emscripten. (C++ class requires some work though)

Comment: Also wasm-bindgen does not generate wasm Interface Types you mention, though it is a promising proposal. Interface Types is not even accepted standard yet. It generates wrappers written in JS currently.

Comment: @BumsikKim, you can only call C++ functions directly if they take/return numbers, but passing something like string requires a lot more work. Sure, I can use embind to generate boilerplate but it will only be for JS and its Emscripten specific (not standard).
Wasm-bindgen can generate interface types, you just need to set `WASM_INTERFACE_TYPES=1` since, as you said, its not stanrad yet.